# Changing Data Insertion technique in the table in prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the following statements in my Data Access Object Implementation code of REST Webservice. Hibernate is also involved.

```
private void createNewHistory(EmployeeHistory history_) throws DaoException
{            
        DataSource ds;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;


        java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
        java.sql.Date sqlNow = new java.sql.Date(now.getTime());

        try {

        ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
        conn = ds.getConnection();      

        // Generate the query
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_HISTORY (");
        sql.append("EMPLOYEE_ID, ");
        sql.append("COMPANY_ID, ");
        sql.append("PREVIOUS_STATUS_ID, ");
        sql.append("CURRENT_STATUS_ID, ");
        sql.append("CHANGE_DATE, ");
        sql.append("CHANGER_ID, ");
        sql.append("EMPLOYEE_STATUS_CHANGE_COMMENT, ");
        sql.append("PREV_REVIEW_STATUS_ID, ");
        sql.append("CUR_REVIEW_STATUS_ID, ");
        sql.append("COMPANY_STATUS_CHANGE_COMMENT ");
        sql.append(") VALUES (");
        sql.append("?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");


        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        ps.setInt(1, history_.getEMPLOYEEId());
        ps.setInt(2, history_.getCompanyId());
        ps.setInt(3, history_.getPreviousStatusId());
        ps.setInt(4, history_.getCurrentStatusId());
        ps.setDate(5, sqlNow);
        ps.setInt(6, history_.getChangerId());
        ps.setString(7, history_.getEMPLOYEEStatusChangeComment());
        ps.setInt(8, history_.getPrevReviewStatusId());
        ps.setInt(9, history_.getCurReviewStatusId());
        ps.setString(10, history_.getCOMPANYStatusChangeComment());

        ... so on and so forth....
```

I am actually concerned about dealing with `PREVIOUS_STATUS_ID` and `CURRENT_STATUS_ID` for two most recent rows in the table.
Say for example the most recent data in the two rows looks like the following (considering only above two IDs)

**Data Scenario #1**

```
        PREVIOUS_STATUS_ID  |   CURRENT_STATUS_ID
              0             |         1001
              0             |         1001
```

So, when I run the above query, the third record in the database based on the current scenario will be inserted like this :

**Data Scenario #2:**

```
         PREVIOUS_STATUS_ID  |   CURRENT_STATUS_ID
              0              |         1001
              0              |         1001 
              0              |         1001
```

Is it possible to make sure that the PREVIOUS_STATUS_ID looks like the following (1001) instead of the above one which is just a copy of the row below:

**Data Scenario #3:**

```
         PREVIOUS_STATUS_ID  |   CURRENT_STATUS_ID
              1001           |         1001
              0              |         1001 
              0              |         1001
```

I am assuming this will involve some if-else statement around these two lines in the above code ?

```
ps.setInt(3, history_.getPreviousStatusId());
ps.setInt(4, history_.getCurrentStatusId());
```

**Edit (More Explanation):**

Considering the `Data Scenario #1` as we can see that a regular pattern is getting established where first column is always getting `0` value and second column 
is always getting `1001` value.

Similarly in `Data Scenario #2`,we can see the same pattern with three rows.

Instead of  having the same pattern followed everytime where first column is getting `0` and second column is getting `1001`, I want to have a scenario like the 
one shown in `Data Scenario#3` where I would like to set the `Previous_status_ID` of most recent record to be of the same value as of `Current_Status_ID`, which 
is `1001` in my case.

Because later on somewhere in my code I would like to do comparison in my code using the WHERE clause like `WHERE Previous_status_ID != Current_Status_ID` and want to filter records based on this .

Comment: what did you mean @Dan i really don't get you

Comment: @YCF_L I added more explanation in my post. Please see and let me know if it's understandable now. Thanks